# How to check if two numbers are statistically significant

Tags: statistics

I have a question on checking if two values are statistically significant. I looked at t-test, but not sure if it applies here.
The data I have is total car accidents (just total values) for 4 years 2016 - 2019 and the total number of preventable car accidents for 2016 - 2019. Is there a statistical test to check if the change between these preventable car accidents values over the years is statistically significant?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: This question should be asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/